# JPA @Query SpringBoot, преобразовать запрос

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

```
import com.company.blog.models.Request;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public interface RequestRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, Long> {

// Последняя запись на первом месте
    List<Request> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();

//Фильтр
    List<Request> findByStatus (String status);

    @Query("SELECT u FROM Request u WHERE u.toWhom = 'Электромонтер'  ORDER BY u.id DESC")
    Collection<Request> findByElectro();
}

mysql> SELECT * FROM request;
+----+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| id | create_date      | end_date         | from_whom           | fulfiled        | level         | room  | status        | text                       | to_whom             |
+----+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 06/06/2021 15:41 | 06/06/2021 17:11 | Клиент              | Гаврилин В. М.  | Срочный       | 1-210 | Выполнено     | Не работает розетка        | Электромонтер       |
|  5 | 06/06/2021 16:35 | 06/06/2021 16:56 | Электромонтер       | Собянина О. В.  | В течении дня | -     | Выполнено     | Требуются хб перчатки      | Зав_хоз             |
|  7 | 06/06/2021 17:08 | 06/06/2021 17:08 | Клиент              | Изилаев Г. А.   | Срочный       | 1-210 | Выполнено     | Не работает розетка        | Электромонтер       |
|  8 | 06/06/2021 17:09 | 06/06/2021 17:09 | Электромонтер       | Толмачев К. С.  | В течении дня | -     | Выполнено     | Требуется раскладушка      | Комплексный рабочий |
|  9 | 06/06/2021 17:10 | 06/06/2021 17:11 | Клиент              | Мужева О. В.    | В течении дня | 1-211 | Выполнено     | Требуется полотенце        | Горничная           |
| 10 | 06/06/2021 18:08 |                  | Комплексный_рабочий |                 | Срочный       | 1-201 |               | >Не работает розетка       | Комплексный рабочий |
| 11 | 06/06/2021 18:12 | 06/06/2021 18:12 | Комплексный_рабочий | Толмачев К. С.  | Срочный       | 1-210 | Выполнено     | Требуется полотенце        | Комплексный_рабочий |
| 12 | 06/06/2021 18:16 |                  | Клиент              |                 | В течении дня | 1-310 |               | Плохо показывает телевизор | Комплексный_рабочий |
| 13 | 06/06/2021 18:26 | 06/06/2021 18:27 | Клиент              | Голованов В. Н. | В течении дня | 1-210 | Выполнено     | Капает кран                | Сантехник           |
| 14 | 06/06/2021 18:27 |                  | Сантехник           |                 | Срочный       | 1-211 |               | Требуется манеж            | Комплексный_рабочий |
| 15 | 06/06/2021 18:29 |                  | Горничная           |                 | Срочный       | 1-211 |               | Сломалась мебель           | Комплексный_рабочий |
| 16 | 06/06/2021 18:30 |                  | Комплексный_рабочий |                 | Срочный       |       |               | Не работает розетка        | Горничная           |
| 17 | 06/06/2021 19:06 | 06/06/2021 19:08 | Электромонтер       |                 |               |       | На выполнении | Холодно в комнате          | Электромонтер       |
| 18 | 06/06/2021 19:27 | 06/06/2021 19:27 | Горничная           |                 | В течении дня |       | На выполнении | Не работает розетка        | Горничная           |
+----+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
```

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, как преобразовать @Query запрос в запрос как у фильтра и вывода записей?

Привожу свою таблицу. Хочу чтобы показывались только те записи где toWhom = 'Электромонтер'. Такая выборка будет в учетной записи Электромонтера
А также Контроллер в котором мы выводим таблицу. C @Query все работает как надо! Но есть ли способ отойти от @Query и составить запрос иначе. В таком формате как составлен фильтр и обратный показ

```
@GetMapping("/StaffAccount")
    public String AllStaffRequest(Model model) {
        Iterable<Request> requests = requestRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
        model.addAttribute("requests", requests);

        Iterable<Request> requests1 = requestRepository.findByElectro();
        model.addAttribute("requests1", requests1);

        return "StaffHTML/staffAccount";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если значение передавать, как параметр, то так:

```
Collection<Request> findByToWhomByOrderByIdDesc(String toWhom);
```

Если же нужно, чтоб значение, по которому фильтруете было зафиксированно, то насколько я знаю, spring data это не поддерживает. По идее такой вариант с default методом, который вызывает обычный метод, должен сработать:

```
Collection<Request> findByToWhomOrderByIdDesc(String toWhom);

// название метода не имеет значения
default Collection<Request> findElectro() {
  return findByToWhomOrderByIdDesc('Электромонтер'); 
}
```